# Postman got null as response's data, even if it sent normally from the service

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, postman

I'm currently working on Graphql API, and I'm fairly new to this.
I have a function that gets a list of jobs, the GraphQl query response's returned the data normally (non-empty array), but when I execute the function that returns this data via postman or Appolo, I got `null` in the response.
Here are the query and the response:

```
query{
    filterJobs(input:{}){
        reward{
            value
        }
    }
}



------ response in postman: -------
{
    "data": {
        "filterJobs": null
    }
}

------ data returned from the function ----
 [ {
    id: 'po876elyhftbo2hy5gone',
    createdAt: '2022-04-22T14:48:23.568162+00:00',
    reward: 60,
    orders: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

the executed function

```
module.exports = async function filter(args) {
  const response = await callContentAPI({
    variables: {
      input:args.input,
    },
    query: `
    query filterJobs{
        jobs
          {
          id
          createdAt
          reward
          order{
            deadline
            deliveryAddress{
              city
              country
            }
          }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });
  
  var jobs = response.data.jobs;
 
  if (!printJobs) {
    throw new Error("Unable to get orders");
  }

  return jobs
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: It will be hard to find the problem without seeing the code that returns this response. (Where is the point where you log "data returned from the function" for example? And what is "the function"?) My spidery senses tell me that you are running your query asynchronously and don't wait for its result, so you return the response before the query even finished executing, but I can't tell whether that's true without seeing the code.

Comment: The console log is just before the return. Yes, I'm using an async function but I'm waiting for the query response.  The problem is, even if I hardcode the response: return {object}, this last will be null.

Comment: I've just edited the question and adding the function

Comment: But which function calls that function and assembles the HTTP response?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.